# google chrome extension :: console.log() from background page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I call `console.log('something');` from the popup page, or any script included off that it works fine.

However as the background page is not directly run off the popup page it is not included in the console.

Is there a way that I can get `console.log()`'s in the background page to show up in the console for the popup page?

is there any way to, from the background page call a function in the popup page?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying "it works fine"? Where are reading "something"? Using console.log() in a popup window shouldn't print in loaded page's console - since the question is 2 years old did the API change?

Comment: if you right click -> inspect popup on your browser action, you'll get a developer tools page for your extension. popup.js will print logs to that.

Comment: @not_shitashi's comment should be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Any *extension page* (except [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)) has direct access to the background page via [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage).

That means, within the [popup page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html), you can just do:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('foo');
```

To make it easier to use:

```
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bkg.console.log('foo');
```

Now if you want to do the same within [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) you have to use [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to achieve that. The reason, they both belong to different domains, which make sense. There are many examples in the [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) page for you to check out.

Hope that clears everything.

Comment: @MohamedMansour, this solution does not work for me. If I `alert()` `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, I get `null`. Do I need to have permissions set or some other configuration?

Comment: @gwg does your extension have a background page? According to the documentation "Returns null if the extension has no background page." https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage

Comment: This works perfectly for my own messages to console. Thanks. Any thoughts on how to also make exceptions etc from popup.js appear in background.js's console?

Answer (score 247):

You can open the background page's console if you click on the "background.html" link in the extensions list.

To access the background page that corresponds to your extensions open `Settings / Extensions` or open a new tab and enter `chrome://extensions`. You will see something like this screenshot.

[image: Chrome extensions dialogue]

Under your extension click on the link `background page`. This opens a new window. 
For the **[context menu sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#context-menus-sample)** the window has the title: `_generated_background_page.html`.

Comment: Cheers, I am aware of this, however opening the background page directly does not invoke anything from the popup page.

Comment: Opening background page doesn't output any console logging information.

Comment: @Hailwood opening the background page doesn't invoke anything but will show the console for background page.

Comment: @Layke once you opened the background page you still have to write into it, i.e. directly use console.log() from the background page or, as mohamed-mansour said, calling the same method on the object returned by getBackgroundPage()

Comment: I found this question searching how to check an extension output (like OP) and found this answer very useful since it allowed me to check the console logging without passing through a content page.

Comment: This link has been updated to "service worker" in more recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: I realise this answer is older than my 9 year old dog, but you just saved me hours of head-scratching! I couldn't figure out why I wasn't seeing any logs and presumed my background service wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 81):

To answer your question directly, when you call `console.log("something")` from the background, this message is logged, to the background page's console. To view it, you may go to `chrome://extensions/` and  click on that `inspect view` under your extension.

When you click the popup, it's loaded into the current page, thus the console.log should show log message in the current page.

Comment: my extension does not have that, other extensions do however ! how do I enable it

Comment: If you have 3 monitors like me...swivel your head. It was opening ChromeDevTools on the opposite end of my monitor array and I didn't see it.

Answer (score 60):

You can still use console.log(), but it gets logged into a separate console.
In order to view it - right click on the extension icon and select "Inspect popup".

Answer (score 18):

The simplest solution would be to add the following code on the top of the file. And than you can use all full [Chrome console api](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) as you would normally.

```
 console = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console;
// for instance, console.assert(1!=1) will return assertion error
// console.log("msg") ==> prints msg
// etc
```

Answer (score 14):

```
const log = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log;
log('something')
```

Open log:

- Open: chrome://extensions/
- Details > Background page

Comment: Would you mind providing some more explanations to your commands?

Answer (score 9):

Try this, if you want to log to the active page's console:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'console.log("addd")'
});
```

Comment: Requires host permissions for the current tab.

Comment: You can add it for testing, and remove if you release the addon.

Answer (score 7):

Update for 2022: with Manifest 3 and service worker, you just need to go to
`chrome://extensions` click `details` button on your extension,
find: `Inspect Views` -> `Service Worker`.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old post, with already good answers, but I add my two bits. I don't like to use console.log, I'd rather use a logger that logs to the console, or wherever I want, so I have a module defining a log function a bit like this one

```
function log(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(...args);
}
```

When I call log("this is my log") it will write the message both in the popup console and the background console.

The advantage is to be able to change the behaviour of the logs without having to change the code (like disabling logs for production, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

In relation to the original question I'd like to add to the accepted answer by Mohamed Mansour that there is also a way to make this work the other way around:

You can access other extension pages (i.e. options page, popup page) from *within the background page/script* with the `chrome.extension.getViews()` call. As described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

```
 // overwrite the console object with the right one.
var optionsPage = (  chrome.extension.getViews()  
                 &&  (chrome.extension.getViews().length > 1)  ) 
                ? chrome.extension.getViews()[1] : null;

 // safety precaution.
if (optionsPage) {
  var console = optionsPage.console;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a console log from a background page you need to write the following code snippet in your background page `background.js`.

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('hello');
```

Then load the extension and inspect its background page to see the console log.

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` I get `null`

and accrouding [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/),

> Background pages are replaced by service workers in MV3.
>
> - Replace `background.page` or `background.scripts` with `background.service_worker` in manifest.json. Note that the service_worker field takes a string, not an array of strings.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

anyway, I don't know how to use `getBackgroundPage`, but I found another solution as below,

### Solution

use the [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#runtime-functions)

So you can inject any script or file. You can directly click inspect (F12) and can debug the function.

for example

```js
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((cmdName) => {
    switch (cmdName) {
      case "show-alert":
        chrome.storage.sync.set({msg: cmdName}) // You can not get the context on the function, so using the Storage API to help you. // https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(([tab])=>{
          chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {tabId: tab.id},
            function: () => {
              chrome.storage.sync.get(['msg'], ({msg})=> {
                console.log(`${msg}`)
                alert(`Command: ${msg}`)
              })
            }
          })
        })
        break
      default:
        alert(`Unknown Command: ${cmdName}`)
    }
  })
```

I create an [open-source](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/tree/f9d37b5/tutorials/extensions/console-alert) for you reference.

Answer (score 0):

To view console while debugging your chrome extension, you should use the `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();` API, after that you can use `console.log()` as usual:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('Testing');
```

This is good when you use multiple time, so for that you create custom function:

```
  const console = {
    log: (info) => chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(info),
  };
  console.log("foo");
```

you only use `console.log('learnin')` everywhere