# How do I debug chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I am learning chrome extension by example. Here is the example I currently learning: http://www.chrome-extensions.net/extensions/mappy/

There are three JavaScript files in this sample project: background.js mappy_content_script.js popup.js.

"mappy_content_script.js" is shown in the Combo box of Scripts tab of Developer Tools.
"popup.js" can be found if I right click the extension icon and choose "Inspect popup".

The problem is I can't debug "background.js" or find it in the Developer Tools. I tried insert "debugger;" in this JavaScript file. I also tried use profiling tool to record the script execution. However, when I click the link of "background.js", a blank page shows up.
[image: Profile Tool]

Is this a bug of chrome or did I miss something? Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`background.js` is loaded in the background. To inspect it visit `chrome://extensions`, find the loaded extension, and "inspect active views" for the background script.

#### Edit

Below is a screenshot of the chrome extensions page. A click on the link `background page` opens the background page for this extension.

[image: Chrome Extensions page]

[Additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829150/google-chrome-extension-console-log-from-background-page/3833157#3833157)

EDIT 2020

Here is how you can see the content scripts and debug,

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!
I wish google could consolidate these three debugging context into just one.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in the animation or if things have changed but I now get to the debug console via chrome://extensions/ -> Inspect views:
background page

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays you have to install a Chrome extension to allow you to inspect the view of a page, specifically the [Develop and Debug Chrome Apps & Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc/related?hl=en-US)

Comment: What does that do that `chrome://extensions` does not?  The interface looks almost identical.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to access your extension code in DevTool and debug it.

Open the DevTool (e.g. F12) , click on "Sources" tab
then look for "Content Scripts" menu next to Page , Filesystem, Overrides etc.
and click on it .

[image]

you should see all active extensions listed there and you can easily add break point to each js code and reload the page to debug through