# Devtools doesn't show console or requests for extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I use console.log heavily to debug when writing JS. I am trying to use it in writing chrome extensions but it is not working. Is there some trickery involved here???

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="width: 200px">
</body>
```

popup.js

```
console.log('test1');
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('test2');
});
```

Neither of these appear in the JS debugger.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

I had this problem as well initially! Make sure you have correct developer tools window opened... I mean, you might have opened the developer tools window for the main page rather than the extension's page (ie. popup.html).

**To open the developer tools window for inspecting the popup, right click on the popup and then click 'inspect element'...** That opens the right developer tools window.

I had made this stupid mistake initially and was stuck.. :)

Comment: Is there a way to send it to the background page's JS debugger? I tried doing this: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().logIt("test log entry"); but nothing happens.

Comment: @gdanko check out the answer to this question. It has the solution i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829150/google-chrome-extension-console-log-from-background-page

Comment: @gdanko `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(...)` works, except that you'll also need to send exceptions to your background page. `try {} catch {}` them and `throw` into your background page at least to know that they happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking at the page developer tools rather than the dev tools for popup which I did not know has separate dev tools.

Comment: how silly we can be sometimes, we still doing mistakes like this in 2022 xD

Comment: How would anyone easily know this, without seeing this SO post?  ;(

Comment: So nice of you. It works.