# Chrome extension window onload jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onload

How am I going to write something when user clicks extension icon and loads the window?

I've already tried

`window.onload = function() {
        console.log("das");
    }`

and ]

`$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document is ready'); 
});`

but still there isn't any log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get Chrome popup.js to use console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858909/cannot-get-chrome-popup-js-to-use-console-log)

Comment: No the console.log is just a debugger, to understand whether it gets there.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The linked answer tells how to open the correct devtools console window for the popup.

Comment: Ok let me explain. When the window is loaded, I want to show a table, but it doesn't. and there isn't any logs in the console. I couldn't trigger window.load in jquery.

Comment: This can be caused by a variety of reasons. One of the most common is using embedded `<script>` elements. If it's not the case simply use the debugger, it can help you solve problems in mere seconds/minutes: open the popup's debugger, set a breakpoint in the code, press F5 in the debugger to reload the popup page and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best idea but you can use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` to communicate between `contentscript.js` and `popup.js`

`contentscript.js` is running directly in page scope so you can easily detect when page is ready. After that you can send a message `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs.id, {action: 'pageReady'});`. In `popup.js` you are listening to:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action === 'pageReady') {
        // Do what you want to do on page ready
    }
});
```

It should works good for you. You can also send response to the caller:

1. `contentscript.js` send information to the `popup.js` that page is ready.
2. `popup.js` do what you want to do (show table).
3. `popup.js` send information to the `contentscript.js` that table is added.

EDIT
I'm not sure about my solution because I found information that:

> The popup, while being an extension page, is not a background page. It
>   is only accessible when it is open

I don't know if it is possible to listen on events in popup. You need to check it.

Comment: It's not even clear what the OP wants and where and what caused the problem. If your guess is right you must be psychic. Otherwise you've wasted your time on a poorly presented question.