# Simple jQuery within <script> tag in Chrome extension popup is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

This is my HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PassVault</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="rainbow"> </div>
    <div id="loginBox">
        <div id="welcome"> Dobrodošli, uporabnik! </div><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After the document loads up, it's supposed to put a red border around all my divs (there's plenty in the HTML file), but it doesn't. I don't see what's wrong here. The jQuery is all in the same file and the link where jQuery is hosted is provided by Google and also works.

It's worth mentioning that the *.html* file is called by `browser_action` from the *manifest.json* file of a Google Chrome extension. So, it opens the popup this way:

[image]

It is also worth mentioning that the above image is just an example image provided by Google. This is not my image. My div's have no borders and the jQuery doesn't change that.

*manifest.json*

```
.... 

"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popupindex.html",
}
....
```

I don't see how this window being a popup would affect the *.js* file functionality but I'm sure it has something to do with that.

Added from comment on an answer by OP:
Adding a border around all these divs was just my way of testing whether or not jQuery works. I will be needing jQuery for plenty of other things in the future. It doesn't even work with this simple thing.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What errors/output do you see in the [console for the popup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14859019/3773011)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to load/run scripts that violate the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). This affects *both* your attempt to load jQuery from a source external to your extension and your attempted use of an inline script (your `$(document).read()` code).

You can access the console for the popup by right-clicking in the popup and selecting "Inspect". The console would have shown you the following errors:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
```

and

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-qMVaiPhbudnaz91QqECVnbdTvKWnqeultnb/Nt/ybo8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

### Extension Default Content Security Policy

For Chrome extensions, the [default Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#restrictions) is:

```
script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'
```

[Google explains that the reasons for this are:](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

> This policy adds security by limiting extensions and applications in three ways:
>
> - [**Eval and related functions are disabled**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval)
> - [**Inline JavaScript will not be executed**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)
>   This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).
> - [**Only local script and and object resources are loaded**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading)
>   Instead of writing code that depends on jQuery (or any other library) loading from an external CDN, consider including the specific version of jQuery in your extension package.

### Loading jQuery

For loading jQuery, the best solution is to download the jQuery code. From the question, the code you are using is at: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`.  However, as mentioned by Ted, that is quite an old version of jQuery. Unless you have a reason to be using an older version, you might try `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js`. You can then store that file in your extension directory (or in a subdirectory) and include it in your *popupindex.html* with

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Your own code

Your own JavaScript code is not running because the default content security policy for extensions does not permit inline scripts. The best solution is to move your `$(document).ready()` code into a separate file (e.g. *popupindex.js*) which is then included in your *popupindex.html* using:

```
<script src="popupindex.js"></script>
```

Obviously, that needs to be after the `<script>` tag that is loading jQuery.

You can include inline scripts, but you will need to supply a "[hash of the script in the "script-src" directive](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage)" in the value for the `content_security_policy` key within your *manifest.json*. However, doing so is just not worth the time and effort.  It is *much* easier to move the code into a separate file.

#### JavaScript included in HTML defined event handlers is also not permitted

Code that you add in HTML for event handlers is JavaScript and is also not permitted.  For example, the following will fail:

```html
<button onclick="doMyThing();">My button</button>
```

You need to code that as:

```html
<button id="doMyThingButton">My button</button>
```

Then, in your separate JavaScript file (see above), something like:

```js
document.getElementById('doMyThingButton').addEventListener('click',doMyThing,false);
```

### Complete extension with popup running jQuery

The following complete extension, which runs your jQuery code, produces a popup which looks like:

[image: popup]

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
    "description": "Demonstrate use of jQuery in a popup.",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "jQuery-in-popup",
    "version": "0.1",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "myIcon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Show panel",
        "default_popup": "popupindex.html"
    }
}
```

*popupindex.html*:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PassVault</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='popupindex.js'> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rainbow"> </div>
    <div id="loginBox">
        <div id="welcome"> Dobrodošli, uporabnik! </div><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*popupindex.js*:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
```

*jquery.min.js*:

Downloaded from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js and stored as *jquery.min.js* in the extension's directory.

Comment: @Makyen what if nothing addon is not able to access the browser memory? how to resolve this?

Comment: @Sarvesh, I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Using the add-on I have stored data in browser. Say xyz is stored in browser local storage. Now there is a button in add-on which will pop-up this xyz taking from local memory and show in alert box... This showing in alert is not working

Comment: @Sarvesh, I'm still not clear on what you are trying to say.  It sounds like you may need to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -3):

Try moving your `script` tag to the bottom of the body, when all the elements have loaded.