# How to use external javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension and I want to use jQuery and [simpleweather.js](http://simpleweather.js).
Purpose of extension is to show outside temperature in new tab with nice background image.
When I use scripts externally HTML site is working and displays temperature but extension is not working.
HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Nová karta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "TimePage", 
    "default_popup": "popup.html" 
  },
  "description": "", 
  "chrome_url_overrides": { 
    "newtab": "timepage.html" 
  },
  "permissions": [ 
    "tabs",
    "cookies"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js" ],
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name": "Temperature", 
  "version": "1.0" 
}
```

When I include scripts locally HTML to the same folder as `timepage.html` is located, site is not working and **does not even display temperature** and extension is not working as well.
HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Nová karta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.css">

    <script src="weather/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "browser_action": {
  "default_title": "TimePage", 
  "default_popup": "popup.html" 
  },
  "description": "", 
  "chrome_url_overrides": { 
    "newtab": "timepage.html" 
  },
  "permissions": [ 
    "tabs",
    "cookies"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "jquery.simpleWeather.min.js", "jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ],
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name": "Temperature", 
  "version": "1.0" 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple jQuery within <script> tag in Chrome extension popup is not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453899/simple-jquery-within-script-tag-in-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-executing)

Comment: You really have two different questions here. You have provided two groups of code which are basically two separate add-ons. The duplicate is for the first one, and the CSS in the second one. An additional issue for the second one is you are loading *jquery.simpleWeather.min.js* prior to *jquery-3.1.1.min.js*. *jquery.simpleWeather.min.js*  appears to require jQuery.  Thus, you need to load jQuery first, not second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem here is the loading order. You should call jquery first simpleWeather and js afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. You just need to change the order of scripts. 
HTML:

```
<head>
    [...]  
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```