# Asynchronous Message Sending In Google Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I have been researching asynchronous function calls and how to set variables to values from them and have had a lot of trouble with it. I want to create a port to message with my file `content.js` on the extension.

To do this I need to receive the tab of the window that I have open, and use its attribute `id` in the `chrome.tabs.connect()` function.
This implementation fails to reach any `console.log()` calls but I don't understand asynchronous programming well enough to understand. Can anyone help with this? My problem is that the two files aren't communicating, so the port isn't opening.

```
<script language = "Javascript">
    function foo(callback){
        var port = chrome.tabs.connect(chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
            //sets curTab to current tab
            console.log(tabs[0]);
            var curTab;
            setTimeout(function(tabs) {
                curTab = tabs[0];
                console.log(curTab);
            }, 5000);

        }),{name: "mode"})

         //both files are preset to this so no need to message
        var mode = "on";

        document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function(){
            if(mode === "off")
                mode = "on";
            else
                mode = "off";
            setMode();
            console.log("clikityclik");
        };


        console.log(mode);


        function setMode(){
            /*sends message to port*/
            if(port)
                port.postMessage({newMode: mode});
            else{
                console.log("error: port not created");
            }
        }   
    }
```

the relevant code from my `content.js` file is below. I call this function once

```
function getMode(){
    /*receives message from port
    **communicates with sandboxed.html
    */
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
        console.assert(port.name == "mode");
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
            if (msg.newMode){
                mode = msg.newMode;
                console.log("Mesage received: "+mode);
            }
            else
                console.log("error receiving new mode, last mode was: " + mode);
        });
    });

}
```

The goal of this program is for the first script to send messages to the `content.js` when a div is clicked and for the 'content.js' file to receive those messages whenever they are sent.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how you are trying to do this.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to *know* what your problem is, but what you have provided strongly implies that this ia a duplicate of: [Simple jQuery within <script> tag in Chrome extension popup is not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453899/simple-jquery-within-script-tag-in-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-executing) and definitely has the issues covered in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate in that the other person was trying to run script that violated the content security policy but mine does not. And my issue is getting the port to send messages with asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to make a function that creates the port, with an input of tab. Basically, `getTab` will try to get the the value of the tab, and if we do have a tab it will run the callback function which is `createPort` which contains the information necessary to create the port and also the event handler for the click on the `div`.

```
function getTab(callback){
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
        console.log(tabs[0]);
        callback(tabs[0]);
    });
}   

function createPort(tab){
    var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id,{name: "mode"});

    document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function(){
        if(mode === "off")
            mode = "on";
        else
            mode = "off";
        setMode(port);
        console.log("clikityclik");
    };
}
var mode = "on"; //mode is preset to on in content.js
getTab(createPort);
```