# Edit page HTML through external Javascript in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first extension ever and I'm somewhat stuck with it, so I'd like the community to give me some orientation on how to do it.

What I want to do is a basic Tab manager, which in first place should **(1)** read all the open tabs in the browser, **(2)** display them in a webpage, and **(3)** allow reordering in the webpage and reflect that in the browser itself.

**UPDATED**

So far I've already done **(1)** with the following code in a file named eventPage.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
    var newURL = "main.html";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});

chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs);
    for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
        var tabURL = tabs[i].url;
        console.log(tabURL);
        writeURL(tabURL);
    }
});

function writeURL(tabURL) { 
    var node = document.getElementById('div1');
    node.innerHTML = '<p>' + tabURL + '</p>';
}
```

Where I'm having problems is with **(2)** because I don't know how to display the information of the tabs in the newly opened main.html; as far as I understand and tested, I can't add script content in the body of the main.html file.

**UPDATED**

The main.html file at this point doesn't do a thing, what i'd like to do is print all far just

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tab & Window Manager</title>
    <script src="eventPage.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Just testing
  <div id="div1">
    <p id="p1">This is part of the native HTML.</p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output I get so far is:
[just the last tab, which actually is the extension tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDwya.png), but I want all tabs to be listed.

So, how can I display all the tabs information in the newly opened html file and what's the best way to do it? I haven't found any example or guide about this specific use case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can reference main.js in main.html in a `<script>` tag. And since main.html is an internal extension page it will have access to chrome.tabs API and thus you can easily create the page contents inside its script.

Comment: Your question is unclear what you are really asking (you state you tried, but don't provide *main.html*). As written, its quite broad and insufficiently detailed to provide you with a specific, detailed, answer. It is really not clear what we would answer here other than pointing you at examples where similar things are done. There are may questions we could point you at. Your *main.html* is just like any other HTML page opened in the background context (e.g. action-popups, option pages, popup windows, tabs) where the top level frame content is a URL from within your extension. (continued)

Comment: Largely, these work very much like any other HTML page, with some added available JavaScript APIs and security restrictions (e.g. all JavaScript must be in a separate file, included with `<script src="<yourFile.js">`. Google has an [options page example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) that works exactly the same whether you load it as an options page, a action-popup, a popup-window, or in a tab.

Comment: It is *unclear* to me if this is a *debugging question without a complete [mcve]*, a general *too-broad* how-to question, or a request for pointers to *off-site* examples. I think the debugging part boils down to a duplicate of [Simple jQuery within  tag in Chrome extension popup is not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40453899)

Comment: I've made some updates to my original post to try to make it more understandable as @Makyen suggested. From the wOxxOm comment that's exactly what I need (at least that's why I think I need); how to create page contents inside a script, for example, build a table in main.html from a script in eventPage.js or other js

Comment: `node.innerHTML = '<p>' + tabURL + '</p>';` overwrites all children of `node` every time you run it. Thus, you only get the last one. In general, you should not use `innerHTML`, because it can lead to quite a few problems. If you are going to use `.innerHTML` here, then what you want is `node.innerHTML += '<p>' + tabURL + '</p>';` (note the `+`). But, this is a *bad* way to do this, for multiple reasons.  You should use `node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>' + tabURL + '</p>');`. See: [`.insertAdjacnetHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: Hmmm... I'd probably write that loop as: `let node = document.getElementById('div1'); tabs.forEach(function(tab) { node.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>' + tab.url + '</p>'); });` (adding a `tabURL` variable, if the `console.log(tabURL);` is desired.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I shouldn't use innerHTML and for your guidance, I was able to print all the tabs URLs! I'll continue working in my extension now.