# Where can I view a console.log written from the chrome dev_tools source js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm playing with chrome dev_tools (the source code, not the app) per https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/contributing as a learning exercise before I write an extension panel.

I curiously noted that console.log statements from these tools do not seem to end up in the console. While this was unexpected at first it makes sense. I also noted that internal dev_tools like Timeline and Console do not seem to have access to "getBackgroundPage" (see [google chrome extension :: console.log() from background page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829150/google-chrome-extension-console-log-from-background-page) for info). Accessing chrome.extension is undefined :(. I can however call console.log, I just seem to be unable to find where this logs to :/.

In the interim I've come up with an annoying workaround where by I make sure each class has a reference to WebInspector.console ala

```
WebInspector.TimelineModel.console = WebInspector.console;
```

And then wrap and use this to make the results of a logging function I wrote end up in inspector console for the tab in question:

```
var bglog = function(obj, thing) {
    WebInspector.TimelineModel.console.log(obj, thing);
};
```

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure, but ssince those are Chrome internals, possibly you could just  output it in normal Chrome-wide logging facilities?

Comment: Yes - this is a duplicate. Just reviewed that link and it addresses the issue. What is the correct thing to do here? vote to close or delete?