# console.log not showing output in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I am using Chrome browser Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit) on Mac OSX 10.11.6.

I have a chrome extension with a background.js where I have a console.log statement for debugging purposes. However, I am unable to see the output in the Chrome browser console. Alert works fine but console.log outputs nothing.

```
alert("CSS code: "+css);
console.log("CSS code:"+css);
```

I have checked to make sure "All" messages are selected, the context is set to "top", etc. When the page loads, I see other console.log messages (not from my extension), the alert window pop up but nothing printed to the console.

How do I see console.log output?

**EDIT:** Adding the function code where the `alert` and `console.log` statements appear.

```
function doSomething(tab) {
    var tabUrl = tab.url;

        if (tabUrl && tabUrl.indexOf("my-site.com") != -1) {

            var css = "";

            if (hideAds == true) {
                css += ".adsBanner {display: none !important;} .promo {display: none !important;} ";
            }

            alert("CSS code: "+css);
            console.log("CSS code:"+css);

            chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
                code: css
            });

        }       
}
```

**EDIT 2:** In response to the comment that this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829150) question, I want to print `console.log` statements from the background file, I don't have a popup.html file. The other question has solutions to execute `console.log` on the background page called from the popup page.

Comment: I initially thought it might be the script not being loaded but if you're sure the alert is showing, could you share the rest of your code so we can replicate?

Comment: Can you try switching the statements so that console log is executed first and let us know what happens? (if you haven't done this already)

Comment: I have added the function code. @mkaran I switched the statements but no dice.

Comment: @zeeshan This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829150/google-chrome-extension-console-log-from-background-page

Comment: OK found this previously answered here that solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: I had a filter set on mine from another project

Answer (score 10):

This has been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension). It seems the background.js has its own console window that needs to be watched (launched from the extension's inpsect view link under chrome://extensions).

Comment: Cheers for this - While having my first go at extensions I did not realize the console output of your background script does get a separate console and it was driving my crazy!

Answer (score -8):

The answer to your problem is to use document.write();

Comment: Care to elaborate why it will solve the issue at hand?

Comment: Writing on the document would be the last debugging resort, isn't it?