# Console.log not showing in console when in listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, console.log

I'm new to javascript so I apologies if this is obvious and everyone knows.

I'm using Message Passing to intruct the background.js of my Chrome Extension to perform an action when you press a button in the extensions popup.js

popup.js:

```
getCurrentTab(function(tab) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        {type: 'status', tabId: tab.id },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response.message)
        }
    )
})
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, callback) {
    console.log("Received message" + message + ", " + sender + "," + callback)
    alert('received')
    callback({message: message.type});
})
```

I've already learned that i need to "Inspect" my popup window for it's console (where I can see the response being printed).

I can see the page is alerting, and I can see the response in my popups console. But the main pages console isn't being filled (with message starting "Received message").

Can someone help a poor js beginner out?

Comment: I think this answer may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17293612/5177045

Comment: FYI: There is no need for message passing between popup page and background script as they both run in the _same context_. A popup page may have direct access to background script's functionality via [`getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) method

Answer (score 0):

@Amedina has rightly suggested my answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17293612/726954

I should be using the extension page to access my background.js console